# Meaning of "grades" in "most grades of diplomat"?

Tags: meaning

In an article of `The Economist`:

> On March 27th the government shocked embassies in Beijing by declaring a halt to the issuing of new identity cards for **most grades of diplomat.**

What does "grade" mean here? I see no applicable meaning of it in any common dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Grade* here is essentially synonymous with [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplomatic_rank).